# How to set the foreign key value as 'NULL'?

Tags: mysql, null, foreign-keys

How to set foreign key in table2 value as  `NULL` when the primary key in the table1 is deleted?
I have created 2 tables `Item`  and `order_item`.

```
Item(item_no(primary key),qty);  
order_item(item_no(foreign key ),order_no);
```

I have created table `order_item` :

```
 create table order_item(  
 item_no int references item on  delete set NULL,  
  order_no  int);
```

Then i  have inserted 5 values in the `Item` table.
Now ,if i  delete the `item_no = 4`in the item  table,its getting deleted  in the `Item` table , but the value of `item_no`is not set to `NULL` in the `order_item`  table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below syntax using explicit `CONSTRAINT [name] FOREIGN KEY ...` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE order_item1(
  item_no int,  
  order_no  int,
  constraint foreign key (item_no) references item( item_no ) on  delete set NULL 
);
```

or add explicitely the foreigng key to the existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE order_item1
ADD constraint foreign key (item_no) references item( item_no ) on  delete set NULL ;
```

Please take a look at this simple test case: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dddf/1

An inline references clause does not work.

The reason of this strange behavoiur is described in documentation, please check this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

> MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.

Inline (inline=next to column definition) reference specyfications are parsed by MySql, but MySql simply ignores them.

Comment: Why have you used another table?

Comment: I've used two tables `order_item` and `order_item1` in the demo to show, using only one test case, how they differ (what will be outcome after running `delete`). If I would use the same table name, it required two test cases.